# GUI user input send TCP command

Tags: tcp, user-input

I would like to create a pop up window that queries for input that will route that input as a string to port 9090. What is wrong with my code?

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9090

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))


def goto(prompt):
    cue = input(prompt)
    while cue not in ("exit", "done"):
        cue = input(prompt)
        byt = cue.encode()
        s.send(byt)
    return cue

print(goto("cue?"))

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Name')

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root,text='okay',command=goto())
b.pack(side='bottom')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please share what the current status of your code is and where you've reached so far.

Comment: The code posted is all I have so far. The code handling the sending of the TCP command is working, I am having trouble fitting that code it into a GUI, which I'm only trying to do because I would like to create a standalone application with py2app.

Comment: I have completed this project, my code is too long to post here, thank you for your time.